# Why do I get different results when replacing a variable by a direct function call?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, typing

I have this code which works just fine:

```
long nodeDistance(node_t a, node_t b) {
    long d1 = abs(a.passi_1 - b.passi_2);
    long d2 = abs(a.passi_2 - b.passi_2);
    return d1 + d2;
}
```

I call it over a linked list, and it returns a plausible, positive result (120259067966). However, when I inline both variables, it acts very weird; I also noticed that it compiles much slower.

```
long nodeDistance(node_t a, node_t b) {
    return abs(a.passi_1 - b.passi_1) + abs(a.passi_2 - b.passi_2);
}
```

When calling it over the same linked list, it will return a negative value (-16322). Why is this?

Comment: formulae for calculating distances differ in the two codes.

Comment: instead of `abs()` both sets of code should be using `labs()`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the second function overflows: `abs` returns an `int`, so the result of `abs(...) + abs(...)` is an `int` (which will sometimes overflow), which is then cast to `long` by the `return` keyword.

On the other hand, the first function casts operands to `long` by storing it in `long` variables, therefore their sum is also a `long`, and it won't overflow.